# How to set system time dynamically in a Docker container

Tags: docker, time

Is there any way to set a Docker containers system time dynamically (at run time) without effecting the host machine?

Using

```
hwclock --set --date "Sat Aug 17 08:31:24 PDT 2016"
```

gives the following error:

```
hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.
hwclock: Use the --debug option to see the details of our search for an access method.
```

Using

```
date -s "2 OCT 2006 18:00:00"
```

gives the following error:

```
date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted
```

**Use case:**

I need to test time sensitive software (behaviour depends on the date).

Other common use cases:

- running legacy software with y2k bugs
- testing software for year-2038 compliance
- debugging time-related issues, such as expired SSL certificates
- running software which ceases to run outside a certain timeframe
- deterministic build processes.

Comment: What would be purpose of doing so? what is your use case?

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29556879/is-it-possible-change-date-in-docker-container

Comment: Actually, I just found and positively tested a solution using the libfaketime
https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime
I'll update with an answer + working example shortly.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**It is possible**

The solution is to fake it in the container. [This lib](https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime) intercepts all system call programs use to retrieve the current time and date.

The implementation is easy. Add functionality to your Dockerfile as appropriate:

```
WORKDIR /
RUN git clone https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime.git
WORKDIR /libfaketime/src
RUN make install
```

Remember to set the environment variables `LD_PRELOAD` before you run the application you want the faked time applied to.

Example:

```
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/faketime/libfaketime.so.1 FAKETIME_NO_CACHE=1 python /srv/intercept/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:3000]
```

You can now dynamically change the servers time:

Example:

```
import os
def set_time(request):
    print(datetime.today())
    os.environ["FAKETIME"] = "2020-01-01"  # Note: time of type string must be in the format "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss" or "+15d"
    print(datetime.today())
```

Comment: For others coming to this solution, be aware that this will not work for golang applications or other statically linked exes.

Comment: Thanks @Sentinel. Funnily enough, I just found this answer via google, I specifically want to use it with a golang app, and I noticed that you left this comment on a 1.5-years-old question just 2 hours ago. Feels like it was for me. Thanks! :)

Comment: Why does is not work in your situation? Does Golang not use system calls to retrieve time? @dimonomid I suggest you give it a try, it’s quick to implement the solution.

Comment: @Vingtoft Let me know if it does in fact work, but search around. Golang doesn't dynamically link in the libraries.

Comment: @dimonomid Yeah I was pretty disappointed. More disappointed with Docker actually. I need to implement timing related tests. This makes Docker pretty much useless as a "container". I would have thought intercepting system time calls for timezone sync would have been item 1 on the Docker agenda. Apparently not.

Comment: I get the error: ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/local/lib/faketime/libfaketime.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.

Comment: @Sentinel Do you have any idea on how to make it work for statically linked exes? (asking just in case you know a new solution after these years have passed... Thanks)

Comment: @dimonomid Did you find a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's `docker-compose` solution:

Add `/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro` to the `volumes` attribute.

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51942316/3702377) for getting an example.

Comment: This is exactly *not* what the question is asking for. You can't use this to dynamically change the time inside the container.

Answer (score -1):

Start the container with an additional environment variable:

```
docker run -e "SET_CONTAINER_TIMEZONE=true" \
           -e "CONTAINER_TIMEZONE=US/Arizona" [docker image name]
```

Comment: Im looking for a way to set the time dynamically, meaning it can be set at runtime. I have updated my question.